# What Cloudflare page rules should be added for a WordPress website to run on HTTPS naked (non www) URLs only?

Tags: wordpress, dns, cloudflare

Here is the existing configuration of my site:

1. I have a CNAME record **www** to **example.com** in Cloudflare DNS settings.
2. Nothing in **.htaccess** of the original host server.
3. WordPress site has its Website and Home address set to **http://example.com**

I don't have a clear understanding of what Cloudflare does and how it integrates with WordPress. However, I would like to achieve this without making any changes in WordPress. What DNS and Page Rules combo should I configure in order to serve all the URLs ONLY **over https without www**?

Based on [this answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/741020/cloudflare-and-www-less-version-of-the-site), I tried changing my DNS settings but it didn't work. And I can't get my head around Cloudflare Page Rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish this you should create two Page Rules.  One that redirects all traffic to https, and another that directs all www traffic to the root domain.

You can find directions for these Page Rules on this [KB article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/224509547) (they are the first two).  Or there is a [video tutorial](https://www.cloudflare.com/features-page-rules/must-use-page-rules/) as well.  If you are already maxed out on Page Rules there is also an option now to purchase additional rules without changing plans.

(I'm from Cloudflare)

Comment: The [link](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/224509547) is spot on. I configured the two rules exactly as stated in the article and it worked. I would like to mention one point which I found crucial: The **Always Use HTTPS** rule should always be first in the list. That's how it worked for me.

Comment: That's great!  Thanks for the added tip.